# How do I change content of array in second tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to send data to a tab bar controller in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. When I send array with data first time it works ok, but when data of array is changed and I send it again array of second tab bar stays the same as it was first time. Can you please help me to understand why is that?
code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [_arrayToPass addObject:[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [_arrayToPass removeObject:[_ingridients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}

NextTableViewController *nextController = (NextTableViewController *)    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

nextController.items = _arrayToPass;
}
```

and then in nextController I want to populate tableView with content of "items" array. 
in

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

    cell.textLabel.text = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? I assume your interface changes based on this array? I think we need to see some code from nexttableviewcontroller to help.

Comment: I populate tableView with content of "items" array and also have NSLog in viewDidLoad of nextController. So.. it shows just content of "items" when array was populated first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague and unclear. You mention that it works the first time but not the second, but then never indicate what that means. You post code that sets a property in your NextTableViewController, but don't give any indication of what you do with that property. Post the method from NextTableViewController that does something with the items property.

If I had to guess, I would guess that you're processing it in your viewDidLoad method, which gets called once and only once when the VC is first displayed.

You should add code in your NextTableViewController's `viewWillAppear:animated` method that does whatever it needs to do with your items property.

Comment: Yes, you right about viewDidLoad. Thanks for that! I added NSLog to viewWillAppear:animated method and I can see changes in array, but I still can populate tableView with this items.. maybe something wrong in cellForRowAtIndexPath method? I just edited my question.

Comment: In your viewWillAppear, add a call to `[tableView reloadData]`;

Comment: Actually, calling reloadData in your viewWillAppear is slightly wasteful, since it means the table view will get drawn twice on the first load. It would be better to create a custom setter for your items property, and call your table view's reload data in that setter. However, I'm guessing that writing a custom setter is beyond your current knowledge.